# Drupal Views Filter Handler

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view

I wrote a custom views handler, that mark message private to 0 or 1 or 2; any is value of hers label [MARK_READ,ARK_NEW,...] :

```
function mydevel_views_data() {
  $data['mydevel']['table']['group'] = t('mydevel');
  $data['mydevel']['table']['join'] = array(
    // Exist in all views.
    '#global' => array(),
  );

  $data['mydevel']['mydevel_isnewmessage'] = array(
    'title' => t('is new message field'),
    'help' => t('is new message field.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'mydevel_handler_field_isnewmessage',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'mydevel_handler_filter_isnewmessage',
    ),  
  );
```

and wrote a filed handler that work properly; message_mark function is wrote on mydevel module file and work currectly; if the message is new that filed label row by "now":

```
class mydevel_handler_field_isnewmessage extends views_handler_field_numeric {

    var $field_alias = 'mydevel_field_isnewmessage';

    function query() {
    }

    function option_definition() {
        $options = parent::option_definition();
        //dsm($this);
        return $options;
    }

    function options_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
        parent::options_form($form, $form_state);
    }

    function get_value($values, $field = NULL) {
        return intval(message_mark($values->mid, $values->message_timestamp));
    }

    function render($values) {
        $value = $this->get_value($values);
        $value_theme = theme('mark', array('type' => $value));
        return $value_theme;
    }

}
```

Now, i want to write a views filter handler that filter on that filed on numeric mode [0 or 1 or 2] or on check list mode [all, read, new, updated]. but I don't want to overwite query function on filter handler and want to use from value that returned by this common handler filed (mydevel_handler_filter_isnewmessage) that added to views filed. can wrote this idea by extend the standard views handler? what i do my dears? I wrote this but not work: this is return error

```
class mydevel_handler_filter_isnewmessage extends views_handler_filter_numeric {
  var $always_multiple = TRUE;

  function option_definition() {
    $options = parent::option_definition();
    return $options;
  }

  function operators() {
    $operators = parent::operators();
    return $operators;
  }

  function query() {
  }

}
```

tank you a lot.